# Trouble with proving certain equality of the covariant derivative of a pseudo-riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections, submanifold, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am trying to fill the details from [this paper](https://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/vol46/iss8/8/) (it's free available) and I get stuck proving the equation (3.16) from the mentioned article. Let me give some context.

**Part 1. Setting the notation.**
Let $M=I \times_f \mathbb{E}_1^2$ the warped product manifold of $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (it is just an open interval) and the Minkowski space of dimension $2,$ $\mathbb{E}_1^2.$ The real-valued function $f$ is always positive.
The metric is given by $\tilde{g}=dt^2+f(t)^2(dx^2-dy^2)$ and $\tilde\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $M.$ Denote by $D$ the Levi-Civita connection of $\mathbb{E}_1^2.$

**Part 2. Principal Equations.**
In order to justify the computations given in the Part 4, I used the following equalities, which a succesfully prove. If $U,V,W$ are *lifts of vector fields tangent to* $\mathbb{E}_1^2,$ we obtain

$$ \tilde\nabla_U V = D_UV -\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\tilde{g}(U,V)\partial_t \qquad (2.1a)$$
$$\tilde\nabla_{\partial_t} U=\tilde\nabla_{U} \partial_t=\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}U \qquad (2.1b)$$
$$ \tilde\nabla_{\partial_t} \partial_t=0. \qquad (2.1c)$$

**Part 3. Parametrization of a isometric immersed manifold.**
Now, let $\varphi: M_q \to M$ an isometric immersion, of a surface $M_q$ of index $q=0,1.$ Let $\xi$ be a local unit  vector field normal to $M_q,$ and write $\partial_t=T+\Theta \xi,$ where $\Theta=\varepsilon_\xi\tilde{g}(\partial_t,\xi).$ It can be easily shown that $T$ is the tangential projection of $\partial_t$ on the tangent space of $M_q$ at each point. The article only focus on the case where $T$ is a nonnull vector field, so that $\Vert T \Vert \neq 0.$ Now, one can show that there is a chart $(u,v)$ on $M_q$ such that $\tfrac{T}{\Vert T\Vert}=\partial_u$ and set $\varepsilon_1=\tilde{g}(\partial_u, \partial_u).$ On this chart, write
$$\varphi(u,v)=(t(u,v),x(u,v),y(u,v)).$$
It is shown that actually $t(u,v)=\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert u,$ so that $t_u=\varepsilon_1\Vert T\Vert$ and $t_v=0.$

Then we have
$$\partial_u=t_u\partial_t+x_u\partial_x+y_u\partial_y=\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t+x_u\partial_x+y_u\partial_y.$$

We set $\varphi_u=\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert  \partial_t+x_u\partial_x+y_u\partial_y=\partial_u,$ so that $\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t=x_u\partial_x +y_u\partial_y$ is a tangent vector to $\mathbb{E}_1^2.$ Hence,
by the definition of $\tilde{g}$ we have
$$\tilde{g}(\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t, \varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t)=\varepsilon_1-\Vert T \Vert^2.$$

Using this observation and  (2.1) we have the following computation.

**Part 4. Computation where I am stuck.**

We assume here that $\Theta$, and hence $\Vert T \Vert,$ is constant. Hence

$$
\tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u} \varphi_u = \tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u- \varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+\tilde\nabla_{\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u- \varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+\tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t} \varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert\partial_t+\tilde\nabla_{\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t} \varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t$$

$$
= D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)-\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\tilde{g}(\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t,\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)\partial_t+\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tilde\nabla_{\partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t}\partial_t+\varepsilon_1^2\Vert T\Vert^2\tilde\nabla_{\partial_t}\partial_t $$
$$
= D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)-\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\left( \varepsilon_1-\Vert T \Vert^2\right)\partial_t+2\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \partial_t} \partial_t
$$

$$= D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)-\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\left( \varepsilon_1-\Vert T \Vert^2\right)\partial_t+2\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}(\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)$$

$$=D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+2\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\varphi_u+\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\left( -\varepsilon_1+\Vert T \Vert^2-2\varepsilon_1^2\Vert T \Vert^2 \right)\partial_t$$
$$=D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+2\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\varphi_u-\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\left( \varepsilon_1+\Vert T \Vert^2 \right)\partial_t$$
$$=D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+2\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert\tfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\left( \tfrac{1}{\Vert T \Vert }+\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \right)\partial_t$$
$$=D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)+2\sigma'(u)\varphi_u-\sigma'(u)\left( \tfrac{1}{\Vert T \Vert }+\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \right)\partial_t.$$

I hope that the **Parts 1,2,3** are enough for you in order to understand all the steps from my computation above. If not, please let me know.

**Part 5. My question**
In the paper, the equation (3.16) is stated as follows
$$\tilde\nabla_{\varphi_u} \varphi_u=\varphi_{uu}+2\sigma'(u)\varphi_u-\sigma'(u)\left( \tfrac{1}{\Vert T \Vert }+\varepsilon_1\Vert T \Vert \right)\partial_t,$$
where I deduce from my computations that $D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)$ must be equal to $\varphi_{uu}$ (I understand that the author means $\varphi_{uu}=t_{uu}\partial_t+x_{uu}\partial_{x}+y_{uu}\partial_{y}=x_{uu}\partial_{x}+y_{uu}\partial_{y}$.) Now, I tried all my ideas in order to show that $D_{\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t} (\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t)=\varphi_{uu},$ but I couldn't get to anything. I tried to use the fact that $\varphi_u-\varepsilon_1 \Vert T \Vert \partial_t=x_u\partial_x+y_u\partial_y$ and the connection $D$ in $\mathbb E_1^2$ is flat, so that $D_{U}V= U(V^1)\partial_x+U(V^2)\partial_y$, being $(V^1,V^2)$ the components of $V$, but it gets me anywhere.

Can you please explain me why such equality holds? Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate it.